# What is wrong in this code?Image Button has to be clicked twice to fire?

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton, commandargument

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("CultureInfo");
    cookie.Value = ImageButton1.CommandArgument;
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    Server.Transfer(Request.Path);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
}
```

The markup is in web control, here it is:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/_48.png"  
                 CommandArgument="en-US" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
```

Comment: Can you show us your `Page_Load` as well? I suspect you may not be checking for `Page.IsPostback` .

Comment: No actually i am not checking on Page_Load.

Comment: Could you show some of your markup?

Comment: The markup is in web control, here it is: <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/_48.png"
    CommandArgument="en-US" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is pertinent in this case but, Server.Transfer will throw ThreadAbortException, just like the default Response.Redirect.  Your final 2 statements will not be executed.

Either move them above the Server.Transfer, use a try/catch/finally block, or see if Server.Execute would meet your needs.  It will return after execution of the referenced page.

Comment: Thanks man it worked, i just moved  Server.Transfer below the code and it worked. Thanks again